# 301 redirects from old URLS to new ones in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, http-status-code-301

I created a new website in Wordpress and I need to 301 all the old URLs to new pages on the new site. Site URL: georgiapivots.com here Old site can be found here: http://georgiapivots.tldealers.com/ please let me know How to get started

Answer (score 0):

You could try the Wordpress plugin [Simple 301 Redirects](https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-301-redirects/) for this.  Alternately, if you're on an apache environment you could add the following to the .htaccess file in the root directory of your old site:

```
Redirect 301 / http://georgiapivots.com/
```

Comment: I installed the above plugin, but you can you please tell me i'm l'm doing url redirecting like this.

This is new site url : http://georgiapivots.com/other-services/riverscreen/

Comment: This is old url : http://georgiapivots.tldealers.com/riverscreen/

This is new url : http://georgiapivots.com/other-services/riverscreen/

In the Simple 301 Redirects Plugin

There is request block area 

/riverscreen/


Destination area 

/other-services/riverscreen
 
and checked use wildcards? save changes

Is this correct way i'm doing please let me know.